# Proper use of bounding box (bb) option of \includegraphics

Tags: graphics

What is the correct way of using bounding box (bb) option of `\includegraphics`?

I have tried several options with different sample files with no luck.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
   \noindent
   \fbox{\includegraphics[bb=0 0 200 30]{temp.png}}\\
   \fbox{\includegraphics[bb=0 0 200 30]{fig.png}}\\
   \fbox{\includegraphics[bb=0 0 200 30]{fig.pdf}}\\
   \fbox{\includegraphics[bb=0 0 7cm 2cm]{fig.pdf}}\\
   \fbox{\includegraphics[]{fig.pdf}}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

All graphics files in the above MWE can be downloaded from my OneDrive folder:

https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aqx30_D8oGfG2RyyU8nZFfv8U5eP

Comment: Which graphics driver are you using that cannot read the size of the images?

Comment: Generally, you don't need to specify the bounding box. You only need this if the image doesn't contain the correct information.

Comment: `bb` only really applies to EPS files but even there you should never need to specify it as latex can read the bounding box from the eps file. If you are trying to show just part of an image use the trim or viewport keys rather than bb

Comment: @cfr: I was mostly experimenting the use of bb for the purpose of clipping. As David suggested viewport works just fine and I will be using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bb` is really only intended for correcting EPS files with incorrect bounding boxes (or PS files that you want to treat as EPS by supplying a missing bounding box)

If you want to trim an existing figure use the viewport, trim or clip options (which just differ in the way in which the coordinates of the region are specified)